# connect nodes with Tikz without crossing other blocks

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I want to connect the blocks B and M in my code without having the connection line "cutting" F. How can I force the connection to enlarge the connecting line and avoid F?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.geometric,arrows,positioning,intersections}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=1cm,thick,
main node/.style={black,draw,minimum width=1.5cm,minimum height=0.75cm}]%circle,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}]

\node[main node] (L)                     {L};
\node[main node] (F) [left = of L  ] {F};
\node[main node] (C) [below = of F  ] {M};
\node[main node] (B)    [right = of L  ] {B};
\node[main node] (AP)    [below = of B  ] {AP};
\node[main node] (A)    [below = of L  ] {A};
\node[main node] (H)  [right = of B  ] {H};
\node[main node] (G) [right = of H] {G};
\node[main node] (BR)  [below = of G] {BR};
\node[main node] (LR)   [below = of BR] {LR};
\node[main node] (U)  [below = of AP  ] {U};
\node[main node] (P)  [below = of U  ] {P};
\path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
(L)      edge node [right]                   {} (B)
(L)      edge node [right]                   {} (F)
(L)      edge node [right]                   {} (C)
(F)      edge node [right]                   {} (C)
(B.north) edge [out=90,in=90] node [right] {} (F.north)
(B.north) edge [out=90,in=180] node [right] {} (C.west)
(B)      edge node [right]                   {} (AP)
(B)      edge node [right]                   {} (A)
(AP.east) edge [out=0,in=270] node [left]    {} (H.south)
(B)      edge node [right]                   {} (H)
(H)    edge node [right]                   {} (G)
(U.east) edge [out=0,in=270] node [left]   {} (H.south)
(P.east) edge [out=0,in=270] node [left]   {} (H.south)
(U)      edge node [right]                 {} (P)
(BR.west) edge [out=180,in=270] node [right] {} (H.south)
(LR.west)  edge [out=180,in=270] node [right] {} (H.south)
(BR.east) edge [out=0,in=0] node [right]     {} (G.east)
(LR.east) edge [out=0,in=0] node [right]     {} (G.east);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

This is what I'm getting now

[image]

and this is what I'd like to get

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! In this case one may introduce an auxiliary coordinate to have finer control over the path. The result will look smooth as long as an `in` and the subsequent `out` differ by 180.

```
\documentclass[11pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=1cm,thick,
main node/.style={black,draw,minimum width=1.5cm,minimum height=0.75cm}]%circle,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}]

\node[main node] (L)                     {L};
\node[main node] (F) [left = of L  ] {F};
\node[main node] (C) [below = of F  ] {M};
\node[main node] (B)    [right = of L  ] {B};
\node[main node] (AP)    [below = of B  ] {AP};
\node[main node] (A)    [below = of L  ] {A};
\node[main node] (H)  [right = of B  ] {H};
\node[main node] (G) [right = of H] {G};
\node[main node] (BR)  [below = of G] {BR};
\node[main node] (LR)   [below = of BR] {LR};
\node[main node] (U)  [below = of AP  ] {U};
\node[main node] (P)  [below = of U  ] {P};
\path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
(L)      edge node [right]                   {} (B)
(L)      edge node [right]                   {} (F)
(L)      edge node [right]                   {} (C)
(F)      edge node [right]                   {} (C)
(B.north) edge [out=90,in=90] node [right] {} (F.north)
(B)      edge node [right]                   {} (AP)
(B)      edge node [right]                   {} (A)
(AP.east) edge [out=0,in=270] node [left]    {} (H.south)
(B)      edge node [right]                   {} (H)
(H)    edge node [right]                   {} (G)
(U.east) edge [out=0,in=270] node [left]   {} (H.south)
(P.east) edge [out=0,in=270] node [left]   {} (H.south)
(U)      edge node [right]                 {} (P)
(BR.west) edge [out=180,in=270] node [right] {} (H.south)
(LR.west)  edge [out=180,in=270] node [right] {} (H.south)
(BR.east) edge [out=0,in=0] node [right]     {} (G.east)
(LR.east) edge [out=0,in=0] node [right]     {} (G.east);
\draw (B.north) to[out=90,in=70] ([xshift=-10mm,yshift=10mm]F) 
to[out=-110,in=180] (C.west);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Or

```
\draw (B.north) to[out=90,in=90] ([xshift=-8mm]F.north west) to[out=-90,in=180] (C.west);
```

[image]

And one can shorten the code a bit, too.

```
\documentclass[11pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,node distance=1cm,thick,
main node/.style={black,draw,minimum width=1.5cm,minimum
height=0.75cm}]%circle,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}


 \node[main node] (L)                     {L};
 \node[main node] (F) [left = of L  ] {F};
 \node[main node] (C) [below = of F  ] {M};
 \node[main node] (B)    [right = of L  ] {B};
 \node[main node] (AP)    [below = of B  ] {AP};
 \node[main node] (A)    [below = of L  ] {A};
 \node[main node] (H)  [right = of B  ] {H};
 \node[main node] (G) [right = of H] {G};
 \node[main node] (BR)  [below = of G] {BR};
 \node[main node] (LR)   [below = of BR] {LR};
 \node[main node] (U)  [below = of AP  ] {U};
 \node[main node] (P)  [below = of U  ] {P};
 \path (L) edge (B)
 (L) edge (F)
 (L) edge (C)
 (F) edge (C)
 (B) edge [out=90,in=90] (F)
 (B) edge (AP)
 (B) edge (A)
 (AP) edge [out=0,in=270] (H)
 (B) edge (H)
 (H) edge (G)
 (U) edge [out=0,in=270] (H)
 (P) edge [out=0,in=270] (H)
 (U) edge (P)
 (BR) edge [out=180,in=270] (H)
 (LR) edge [out=180,in=270] (H)
 (BR) edge [out=0,in=0] (G)
 (LR) edge [out=0,in=0] (G);
 \draw (B) to[out=90,in=90] ([xshift=-8mm]F.north west) 
 to[out=-90,in=180] (C.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```